# Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b error calling a SOAP service after receiving result of a REST call - WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Implementing a service chain in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 we have a sequence that calls a REST service and in the receiving sequence we call a SOAP service. In doing so, we get the following error,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>ns2:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)</faultstring>
</ns2:Fault>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
```

This happens irrespective of whether we use the result of the previous call as input or even when actual values are hard-coded in the PayloadFactory. Moreover the SOAP service never receives the request.

When the SOAP service is called on it's own through the ESB or through soapUI, it works fine.

The sequence that calls the SOAP service is as follows,

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="tmpl_get_customer_details">
   <sequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
         <format>
            <getCustomer xmlns="http://customer.frontend.ws.utilibill.com.au/">
               <customer xmlns="">
                  <custNo>12965</custNo>
               </customer>
               <login xmlns="">
                  <password>password</password>
                  <userName>username</userName>
               </login>
            </getCustomer>
         </format>
         <args>
            <arg xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$ctx:utilibill_customer_number" evaluator="xml"></arg>
         </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log level="full">
         <property name="POSITION" value="tmpl_get_customer_details"></property>
      </log>
      <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://customer.frontend.ws.utilibill.com.au/UtbCustomer/getCustomerRequest"></header>
      <header name="To" scope="transport" value="http://customer.frontend.ws.utilibill.com.au/UtbCustomer/getCustomerRequest"></header>
      <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
      <log level="full">
         <property name="POSITION" value="CALLING_CUSTOMER_SERVICE"></property>
      </log>
      <send receive="seq_get_services">
         <endpoint key="UtbCustomer"></endpoint>
      </send>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

Can anyone please point out what maybe causing this?

Comment: One thing I noticed that even though you've defined a sequence template you've not declared the input parameters on top (like the last issue :) ). Are you passing the username and password as arguments? Then they would  be parsed as `null` in the sequence template.

Comment: Thanks Chamila. While your observation on the missing parameters is correct in this instance the template does not have anything parameterised. I'm trying this out with all values hard-coded.